# I want to publish my app also for sdk10 (2.3.3)

Tags: android, layout, sdk, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've tried many things and read a lot, but I haven't got it out how to do...

xml-layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            tools:context=".ActivityMain_plain">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button_berechnen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="@string/Button_berechnen" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button_berechnen"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/input_ipAdresse"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</EditText>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/input_snm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_ipAdresse"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/input_snm"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/Button_berechnen"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_medium" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button_berechnen"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_snm"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_medium" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

        </GridLayout>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_Klasse"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_Klasse_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_BitsNetz"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsNetz_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_BitsSubnetz"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsSubnetz_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_BitsHost"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_BitsHost_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_MagischeZahl"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_MagischeZahl_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_AnzSubnetze"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlSubnetz_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:text="@string/txt_AnzHosts"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tV_AnzahlHost_erg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_small" />

        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Eclipse GUI error:

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'editTextStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'autoCompleteTextViewStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'scrollViewStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- GridLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Good idea how to implement GridLayout *(or good alternatives)*?

I've switched the styles to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Back" />
```

I've made values-v10 and lyout-v10 folders of course

I've tried to load the Android.jar from 2.3.3 but that didn't help for the first *error lines from eclise gui*

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout is not supported until Android 4.0 (SDK API level 14).  You need to use TableLayout instead to support older versions.